# SquareSpace: Change section background color (Eamon / Ethan template)

Tags: css, background-color, squarespace

Example template:
https://eamon-demo.squarespace.com/#overview-eamon

Is there any possible way to change the background color of a *single* white section with text in the Ethan / Eamon theme? I've had no luck with

```
<style>
.body { 
background-color: lightblue; 
}
</style>
```

in the Advanced section of the page editor. I am looking to change only one of the section's background colors, I do not want to change them all. Thanks.

Solution!
I was able to make it work on a section called "titles" adding the following to the CSS Editor:

```
section#titles { 
background-color: lightblue !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by targeting via the [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). For example:

```
[data-url-id='titles-eamon'] .content, [data-url-id='titles-eamon'] .content-inner {
    background-color: lightblue !important;
}
```

The above code would be inserted via the [CSS Editor](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor). The `data-url-id` value corresponds the URL Slug of the index page section (see image).

You can inspect the code of the page user your [browser's developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) (often by hitting F12 or CTRL+SHIFT+I). That will help you explore the code of the page for this and other similar issues/customization.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the "titles" section working with:
    section#titles {
        background-color: lightblue !important;
    }